# POST to BotFramework using Node

Tags: node.js, azure, botframework, bots

I have a BotFramework v4 deployed in Azure using the virtual agent template and have been trying to POST to the endpoint to have a message sent to users in Teams but the response received is a 400 Bad Request. We can perform a POST using Postman with the same information and it will post without issue. The Bot is deployed using C# while the software we are using requires node to perform the fetch/https request.

Local testing of the code is below with some information redacted. Tried using HTTPS request as well and got the same results of 400 Bad Request

**Update**
We got an HTTPS request working in local testing but once published to Azure and sending the POST to the Azure url, we get a 200 response but the POST is not going to the MS Teams conversation as expected. Application insights shows no errors.

**Update 2**
Using live metrics found that when sending the POST to the bot this is the error received:
System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null. (Parameter 'clientSecret')
at Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.ClientCredential..ctor(String clientId, String clientSecret)
at Microsoft.Bot.Connector.Authentication.MicrosoftAppCredentials.b__14_0()

Comment: Is this still an issue for you? Can you double check that both the MicrosoftAppId and MicrosoftAppPassword properties (with values) are stored in your bot's app service's configuration?